# remote: ! Precompiling assets failed. (Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

So, I typically don't have any issues deploying apps to heroku, however, in this specific case I'm getting a precompile failed error...

**This line here stands out to me:**

```
remote:        NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

**But here are the full error logs:**

```
remote:        Bundle completed (9.35s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote:        Removing carrierwave (0.10.0)
remote:        Removing foreigner (1.7.4)
remote:        Removing mailboxer (0.12.5)
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
remote:        (in /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/sass_functions.rb:63:in `sprockets_context'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-4.0.5/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:23:in `asset_url'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/funcall.rb:113:in `_perform'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/node.rb:40:in `perform'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:298:in `visit_prop'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:100:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `block in visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `map'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:109:in `block in visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:121:in `with_environment'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:108:in `visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `block in visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:356:in `visit_directive'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:100:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `block in visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `map'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:109:in `block in visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:121:in `with_environment'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:108:in `visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `block in visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:128:in `visit_root'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:100:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:7:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/engine.rb:315:in `_render'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/engine.rb:262:in `render'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:24:in `evaluate'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:25:in `initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:211:in `block in find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:257:in `benchmark'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:210:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:119:in `block in compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:146:in `with_logger'
remote:        /tmp/build_3dacd5df86a31726215c3dc3c1c22600/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to fakename-dev.
remote: 
To git@heroku.com:fakename-dev.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:fakename-dev.git'
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this?

Cheers!

Comment: Can you update your post with the contents of `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`?  Seems like something here is producing the error.

Comment: @steveklein application.css just contains basic require assets. The error might be from some of the file that's required, but we can't find it, it compiles without errors on local machine in production ENV.

Comment: @steveklein, anyway, here it is https://gist.github.com/rmagnum2002/0a5fe0f2c8dbf2fda4ea

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: @steveklein latest rails, solved it, thank you for your willing to help.

Comment: Good news!  And nice write up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the deal, we had `application.css` that somehow ignored the errors in other `.scss` files on precompile, so we had assets precompiled on local but couldn't precompile them on heroku.

I decided to rename `application.css` to `application.css.scss` and now when I was running `assets:precompile` task I got errors the same as on heroku and this allowed me to investigate where the problem was.

It was a minified bootstrap.css file(came from the designer), that a dev in our team decided to re-factor by indenting it and change path to fonts without changing the extension to `.scss` to get the `image-url` and `asset-url` helpers available.. Anyway, I dropped all of that and used bootstrap gem that fixed the problems with icons.

**To sum it up**, add `.scss` to your stylesheets to find faster where the problem is while precompiling.

Answer (score 2):

Run the command: `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`, and you can sort out the error easily.

Comment: We did this many times and precompile was successful each time, only renaming the manifest to `.scss` returned the same error as on heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this can happen due to many reasons, but in my case, adding this line `public_root_path: public`
 to **webpacker.yml** has solved the issue

```
default: &default
  public_root_path: public
  ...
```